# How to globally disable eldoc?

Tags: eldoc

Using Rust/Racer/Eldoc is causing performance problems while navigating around the file (hanging while `eldoc` is fetching the docs).

Running `eldoc-mode` reports that it's disabled but still runs Racer's `eldoc` function.

Is there a way to globally disable `eldoc`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since Emacs 25.1 a new global minor mode `global-eldoc-mode` exists, and is enabled by default.

To disable it, simply add this to your init file:

```el
(global-eldoc-mode -1)
```

You can alternatively `(setq-local eldoc-documentation-function #'ignore)` in buffers for which you wish eldoc to have no effect, without disabling it elsewhere.

Comment: One should note that calling eldoc via `M-x eldoc` still works; it displays the documentation for the symbol at point in a new buffer, which is nice.