# How do I disable python-help

Tags: python

I just upgraded to Emacs 26.1 on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04, but emacs26 from the kelleyk repo).

python-mode is now bringing up a *Python-Help* window whenever the cursor in on a symbol or keyword.  I'm finding this very distracting because it messes with my buffer layout and moves the cursor around.

It's a nice idea, but I don't want it happening automatically.

How can I disable the automatic *Python-Help* window?

Comment: Have you tried running Emacs without your init file (`emacs -q`)?

Comment: If I do "emacs -q" it doesn't exhibit the bad behavior.  However, evaluating everything in my .emacs; doesn't make it start (even after reloading the python file).  So it's not something that I've configured.  What does -q remove beyond my .emacs?

Comment: Maybe it's related to when certain settings are set.

Comment: The manual states for `emacs -q`: "Do not load your Emacs init file `~/.emacs`, or `default.el` either. " https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs-20.7/html_chapter/emacs_37.html#SEC492

Comment: Disable `eldoc`

Answer (score 5):

nega nailed it.  Turning off eldoc fixed my problems.  I would have never know that was what to look for.

More detail here:
[How to globally disable eldoc?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-to-globally-disable-eldoc)